# Screen Flashes when using datastore to update UI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-jetpack-datastore

I am using Jetpack Compose to build my UI and when a user enters the app, the app will first check whether he/she is a first time user.

If it's a first time user, it will load the `ScreenStarter()` composable. Else, it will load the `AppContent()` composable.

My code is like that:

App.kt

```
 {
    /**
     * This is the Main MES app that will
     * determine which screen content to show
     **/

    /** Load the app settings from datastore **/
    val appSettings = application.datastore.data.collectAsState(initial = MesAppSettings()).value

    /** Set the correct app theme that the user has set **/
    val darkTheme = when (appSettings.appTheme) {
        AppTheme.FOLLOW_SYSTEM -> isSystemInDarkTheme()
        AppTheme.DARK -> true
        AppTheme.LIGHT -> false
    }

    MesTheme(
        darkTheme = darkTheme // Load the app theme
    ) {

        
        /** Determine screen content **/
        if (!appSettings.isFirstTimeLogging) {
            AppContent(
                application = application,
                appSettings = appSettings,
                widthSizeClass = widthSizeClass
            )
        } else {
            ScreenStarter(
                application = application,
                requestMultiplePermissions = requestMultiplePermissions
            )
        }

    }
}
```

The issue here is that, if it is a recurrent user and he/she opens the app, the screen flashes, and we can briefly see the `ScreenStarter()` composable before it switches to the `AppContent()` composable. I think this happens because the data is fetched asynchronously from the data store.

Can someone advise on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some different initial value for appSettings. You can use `null` for example, then if `appSettings` is null, show blank screen or some progress indicator, if it's not null, you know that correct data has been loaded from storage and you can show content based on your logic.